# Symfony 3 app works on local host but once deployed on the server, the main page works but other links are broken

Tags: symfony, symfony-3.2

Do I have to change something on the configuration server.  the main page works on  on /web or web/app.php but the other links dont work.  it returns a 404 error.  can someone please help.

Comment: Can you check your routing with this command : app/console de:ro. 
if you not see your routes you must check the importation of those routes

Comment: Looks like your webserver is configured to ignore .htaccess configurations. Take a look at [Configuring a Web Server](http://symfony.com/doc/current/setup/web_server_configuration.html), specifically the `AllowOverride` directive.